# RTMP android aftek

Tags: android, video-streaming, red5, rtmp

I am trying to implement the library from http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml
to stream live video from a red5 server.

On the server i am using the simpleBroadcaster and i want to stream it to the android phone.

my code:

```
package com.cu.reader;

import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Map;
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpClient;
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpStream;
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpStreamFactory;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.MetaData;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.RTMPData;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.VideoCodec;
import com.al.rtmp.message.Metadata;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class StreamreaderActivity extends Activity implements RtmpClient {
     RtmpStream stream = null;
     Boolean connected = false;
 String server = "rtmp://216.224.181.197/oflaDemo/";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    stream = RtmpStreamFactory.getRtmpStream();
    stream.setClient(this);
    stream.connect(server);
}
@Override
public void streamCreated() {
    Log.i("stream","Connected!");       

    connected = true;
    stream.setPlayName("red5StreamDemo");
    stream.play();

}
@Override
public byte[] getWriteData(int length) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void invoke(String arg0, Object... arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
;   
}
@Override
public void onDataReceived(RTMPData rtmpData) {
    MetaData metaData = rtmpData.getMetaData();
    VideoCodec vc = metaData.getVideoCodec();
}
@Override
public void onError(Exception ex) {
    Log.e("ClientException", " Some exception occurred." + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
@Override
public void onMetaDataReceived(Map map) {
    Log.i("code","METADATA:" + map);        

}
@Override
public void onResult(String method, Object... arg1) {
    Log.i("result","METADATA:" + method);       

}
@Override
public void onStatus(String code) {
    Log.i("code",code);     
}

}
```

i am always receiving  NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound in onStatus function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream does not exist, correct.  But why? Probably one or two reasons: you have not created a live broadcast stream and 2) because you are using the wrong scope.  Unless you configure it differently by hand (which is unlikely), use the 'live' broadcaster scope, which is in /live.

Thus, publish to rtmp://216.224.181.197/live/red5StreamDemo and to subscribe to the exact same mrl, in this example rtmp://216.224.181.197/live/red5StreamDemo.  NOTE: for this to work, you need to create a 'live' stream and feed it to your RED5 server.  You can use avconv (aka ffmpeg) to create an rtmp feed.

Answer (score 1):

You get NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound error becouse such stream doesnt exist on red5 application.

I made quick as3 test to check:

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;

public class LearnWowzaClient extends Sprite {

    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var video:Video = new Video();

    public function LearnWowzaClient() {

        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.client = this;
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNet);
        nc.connect("rtmp://216.224.181.197/oflaDemo/");
    }

    private function onNet(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        trace(event);
        trace(event.info.code);
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                tryPlayStream();
                break;
        }
    }

    private function tryPlayStream():void {
        trace("playStream");
        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
        ns.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, onAsyncError);

        ns.play("red5StreamDemo");
        video.attachNetStream(ns);
    }

    public function onBWCheck(parameter:Object = null):void {
        trace("onBWCheck p=" + parameter);
    }

    public function onBWDone(parameter:Object = null):void {
        trace("onBWDone p=" + parameter);
    }

    private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("onIOError");
    }

    private function onAsyncError(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void {
        trace("onAsyncError");
    }

    private function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        trace("onNetStatus   ", event.info.code);
    }
}
}
```

I also get NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound error.
Can you show red5 application code?

Comment: is this library really work i couldn't find any tutorial on this

Comment: Hi, Gabriel. What library did you mean? I wrote just a simple pure sa3 code.